# How do I get value of field in nested gridview where checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a nested gridview inside another gridview.  The parent gridview has a list of tasks, and each task has a list of steps (the child gridview).  Each step has a checkbox so once a user is done with a step, he'll check the checkbox and that will fire the CheckChanged event in which I have a stored procedure to update the database so the checked step registers as completed.

I have a CheckChanged event that looks for the step ID of the row the checked checkbox was in, then fires off the stored procedure using the step ID as an input parameter.  This works.  However, steps can be added, and for some reason, when a check box on an earlier step is clicked, the code that looks for the step ID won't go backwards and recognize the step ID.  In other words, if a if the the step ID of a certain task is 20, and it is checked and the event fires off, if I add a step to an earlier task (a task listed higher on the gridview) and that step has an ID of 21, clicking on it will constantly register the step ID as 20, as if the CheckChanged event doesn't recognize a step added to another task.  Here is my code:

aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
                DataKeyNames="TaskID" 
                runat="server" 
                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound" 
                CssClass="DefaultGrid" 
                onRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
                EmptyDataText = "<br/>There are no Tasks in this Project." 
                AllowPaging="True" 
                AllowSorting="True" 
                CellPadding="4" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_mp_Display_Tasks_Home" 
                ForeColor="#333333" 
                GridLines="None" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <RowStyle CssClass=" table-responsive body-content " />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" />          
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="Images/plus.png" />                                           
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display:none">                                          
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" 
                                    runat="server" 
                                    onRowCommand="GridView2_RowCommand"  
                                    Datakeynames="TaskStepID"
                                    CssClass="ChildGrid" 
                                    EmptyDataText="<br/>There are no Steps in this Task." 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                                    onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <Columns>                                                                     
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskStepID" HeaderText="TaskStepID" Visible="true" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskID" HeaderText="TaskID" Visible="false" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskStepTypeID" HeaderText="TaskStepTypeID" Visible="false"/>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskStepPriority" HeaderText="Task Step Priority" Visible="false" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="70%" DataField="TaskStepDesc" HeaderText="Step Description" />                                   
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Step Completed" ItemStyle-Width="15%"  >
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemTemplate>  
                                    <asp:Checkbox  ID="TaskStepCompleted"  
                                                    OnCheckedChanged="TaskStepCompleted_CheckedChanged" 
                                                    Checked='<%# Eval("TaskStepCompleted") %>' 
                                                    runat="server"                                                                                                                      
                                                    AutoPostBack="true" />                                                          
                                </ItemTemplate>                                                            
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskStepComment" HeaderText="TaskStepComment" Visible="false" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Step Activity" ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                                <ItemTemplate>       
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Add" ID="Addstep" runat="server" CommandName="addstep" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskStepID") %>'/>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" ID="Editstep" runat="server" CommandName="editstep" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskStepID") %>'/>                                                              
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" ID="Deletestep" runat="server" CommandName="deletestep" OnClientClick="return confirm('<%=AlertMe%>');" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskStepID") %>'/>                                                                                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>                                                            
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskID" HeaderText="Task ID" Visible="false"/> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProjectID" HeaderText="Project ID" Visible="false" />               
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskTypeID" HeaderText="Task Type ID"  Visible="false" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskCompleted" HeaderText="Taske Completed?" Visible="false"  />                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskCreationDate" HeaderText="Task Creation Date" Visible="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskSubmitterID"  HeaderText="Task Submitter ID" Visible="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentID" HeaderText="DepartmentID" Visible="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskDueDateCommentType" HeaderText="Due Date Comment" Visible="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskLastUpdatedDate" HeaderText="Task Last Updated Date" Visible="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskLastUpdatedUserID" HeaderText="Task Last Updated UserID" Visible="false"  />                
        <asp:BoundField DataField ="TaskSubmitterName" HeaderText="Task Submitter Name" Visible="false"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskLastUpdatedUser" HeaderText="Task Last Updated User" Visible="false"  />                
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentDesc" HeaderText="Dept" visible="false"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Description">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="TaskDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# HighlightText(Eval("TaskDescription").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="40%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="% Comp.">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="PercentCompleted" runat="server" Text='<%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("PercentCompleted").ToString()) ? "0" : Eval("PercentCompleted")) + " %" %>' ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskDueDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Task Due Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}" visible="true"/> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskTypeName" HeaderText="Task Type" visible="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentAbbrev" HeaderText="Dept" Visible="true"  /> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity">
            <ItemTemplate>       
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" ID="Edittask" runat="server" CommandName="edittask" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>'/>                                                              
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" ID="Deletetask" runat="server" CommandName="deletetask" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you wish to Delete this Task?');" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>'/>                                                                                                   
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Comments" ID="Detailstask" runat="server" CommandName="detailstask" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>'/>  
            </ItemTemplate>                                                            
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>           
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_mp_Display_Tasks_Home" runat="server" FilterExpression="TaskDescription LIKE '%{0}%'" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IntelliBaseConnectionString_mp_Display_Projects_Home %>" SelectCommand="mp_Display_Tasks_Home" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Incoming_ProjectID" Type="Int32" />                          
    </SelectParameters>
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="TaskDescription" ControlID="txtSearchtasks" PropertyName="Text"/>
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

cs:

```
protected void TaskStepCompleted_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this nested foreach grabs the taskstepID number for the row in which the checkbox was just checked.
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView GridView2 = (GridView)row.FindControl("GridView2");

            if (GridView2 != null)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow Row in GridView2.Rows)
                {
                    if (Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chk = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)Row.FindControl("TaskStepCompleted");
                        if (chk.Checked || !chk.Checked)
                        {
                            Session["TaskStepID"] = GridView2.DataKeys[Row.RowIndex]["TaskStepID"].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // autopost back the check box to run the stored procedure
    var TaskStepID = Session["TaskStepID"].ToString();
    var ProjectID = Session["ProjectID"].ToString();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=orlandosql1;Initial Catalog=IntelliBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=trainingsurveys_webuser;Password=C@mb3rSQL;"))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.mp_Task_Step_Completed_Toggle", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TaskStepID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TaskStepID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AdminUserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "10";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LogActionItemID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = "15";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime.ToString("d")).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        Response.Redirect("Tasks.aspx?id=" + ProjectID.ToString());
    }           
}
```

I tried my best to describe the issue.  To recap:  nested gridview has rows with check boxes.  Clicking the checkbox automatically updates db tables, but regardless of check box row, the CheckedChanged code will only register the ID of the most recent ID.  Any insight is appreciated.

Carlos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe your issue comes with how you think you are grabbing the `TaskStepID` of your GridViewRow. You are doing a lot of unnecessary work. Instead of iterating every row of both GridViews, just grab the GridViewRow of the CheckBox that was just clicked.

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)cb.NamingContainer;
GridView gv = (GridView)row.NamingContainer;
string taskStepID = gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Notice how by iterating each row like you were, you were always getting the `TaskStepID` of the last row. So when you added a row before it, it was using the last row instead of the one you expected.

Comment: That is exactly my problem!  That looks like a much better solution for finding the row index.  However, Gridview2 is out of context.  How would I be able to put it in context without needing to iterate every row in both gridviews?

Comment: Good catch, sorry about that. Check my edit. What you want to do is find the NamingContainer of the control to get the row. Then find the NamingContainer of the row to get the GridView. NamingContainer will go up the control tree until it finds a control that implements INamingContainer.